# Mysql : how to use column name as a filter in subquery?

Tags: mysql

I cannot find the right syntax to use a column from a table in a subquery.

In the following query, I want to make a sum of DISTINCT value from a subquery.
That results in an error : Unknown column wo.`CODE_WORKORDER` which is related to the HAVING clause. If I replace wo.`CODE_WORKORDER` by '17593', it works.

Any idea ?

```
select 
(
    select 
        sum(der.UC)
        FROM
            ( select distinct
                wo2.CODE_WORKORDER,
                invl2.UNITCOST as UC
            from
            tbl_workorder as wo2 inner join
            tbl_workorderitem as woi2 on wo2.CODE_WORKORDER=woi2.FK_CODE_WORKORDER inner join
            tbl_invoicesource as invsrc2 on wo2.CODE_WORKORDER=invsrc2.FK_CODE_WORKORDER inner join
            tbl_invoiceline as invl2 on 
            (invsrc2.FK_CODE_INVOICE=invl2.FK_CODE_INVOICE AND woi2.FK_CODE_ITEM=invl2.FK_CODE_ITEM)
        HAVING
            wo2.`CODE_WORKORDER` = wo.`CODE_WORKORDER`) as der
)
from 
    tbl_workorder as wo
where
    wo.`CODE_WORKORDER` = '17593'
```

Comment: *Any idea ?* rewrite from correlated subquery to a JOIN.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Learning how to use `HAVING` will be a good start.  `HAVING` is to be used to gather with `GROUP BY`.  Here's one of the many links available on the web.  https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/group-by-having-clause-sql

Comment: @Eric *`HAVING` is to be used to gather with `GROUP BY`.* MySQL extension allows HAVING without GROUP BY (hidden `GROUP BY RAND()` applied).

Comment: @Akina What does `GROUP BY RAND()` even mean?  It doesn't make any logical sense.

Comment: @Eric *It doesn't make any logical sense.* ??? why? Normal logic - each separate record is a group. Or you suppose that `GROUP BY id` where `id` is primary key makes no sense too?

Comment: @Akina There's nothing wrong with `GROUP BY Id`.  You know you're grouping by Id.  But `GROUP BY RAND()` ...

Comment: It looks like `CODE_WORKORDER` is a constant??

Comment: The answer was in a post I didn't find at first eye : "Subquery can't find column from superquery's join" : You have 2 layers of nesting and the reference of table wo cannot "see" through these 2 layers in MySQL. Thanks for help to the one who answered.